# Cypress Code Coverage of an app that has: Razor pages, JavaScript, Jquery tech stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress, code-coverage

I'm trying to do Cypress Code Coverage for my End-to-End tests written in JavaScript

I am using version 12.8.1 of Cypress. I've done everything that is in this tutorial: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/code-coverage. But it doesn't work.

I also get this message in my terminal after running the script:
Could not find coverage file **.nyc_output\out.json

The test pass and are executed and it generates my report but it's like this:
[HOW MY REPORT LOOKS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOMQQ.png)

Also some more info, the code that needs to be instrumented is in a different dir, and the cypress config is in another dir.

If anyone has any ideas about this, please let me know :)

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my app wasn't running the instrumented code...